# How to align back button of the navigation controller to its left corner in iphone application

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, customization

I have customized my navigation controller back button by adding image to it,but still I couldn't get back button in to navigationbar's left corner.I want to avoid the gap or the space between navigation bar's left margin and the backbutton.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code you can use

```
 UIButton* backButton= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
//here in below you just need to pass the point where you want to place your button.
```

As you said you need `space between navigation bar's left margin and the back button.`

```
[backButton setFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin, yOrigin, width, height)];
[backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIBarButtonItem * leftBarButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem= leftBarButton;
```

I hope it may help you.